# How to manipulate html <table> tags in between javascript function?

Tags: javascript, html

For example: 
 problem:
             Make a corresponding table cell red colored.
            I know I must use the .tag className in the style
             but I don't know how to make the color changed for 
             html tags in javascript that sits in another function.

---

```
<style>
       .tag { background-color : red ; }
</style>
<script>
var str = ["B","I","N","G","O"];
function table()
{

      t+= "<tr>";
     for(b=0;b<5;b++)
     {
      t+="<td>"+ document.getElementById("table").innerHTML + str[b] + "</td>";
     }
    t+="</tr>";
}
function changeColor()
{
  var letter= document.getElementById("matching").value;
   for(i=0;i<5;i++)
   {
      if(letter == str[i])
      {
        /*
          here.
       */
      }
   }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I'm guessing you mean something like `document.getElementById("table").getElementsByTagName("td")[i].className="tag";`

Comment: I think what you want to do is have different tags/classes for different colors. This way you just add/remove/toggle a particular tag/class to the cells you want to update.  But you have to be able to select those cells uniquely, or in groups depending on the functionality you require.  When you create the table you assign unique IDs to the cells, and classes for groups of cells (e.g. odd/even rows or column classes)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var str = ["B", "I", "N", "G", "O"];

function table() {
  t += "<tr>";
  for (b = 0; b < 5; b++) {
    t += "<td" + (changeColor() ? " class='tag'" : "") + ">" +
      document.getElementById("table").innerHTML + str[b] +
      "</td>";
  }
  t += "</tr>";
}

function changeColor() {
  var letter = document.getElementById("matching").value;
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (letter == str[i]) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

I would make a demo, but I have no idea about the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example that might help you:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        td {
            border: 2px solid green;
            padding: 30px;
        }
        .yellowColor{
            background-color: yellow;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    Enter Letter : <input type="text" id="matching">
    <br><br>
    <table id="tab">
        <tr>
        <td>a</td><td>b</td></tr>
        <tr><td>c</td><td>f</td></tr>
        <tr><td>b</td><td>a</td></tr>
    </table>
    <script>
        var tds = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
        var ele= document.getElementById("matching");
        ele.onkeyup =function(){changeColor();}
        function changeColor() {
            var i = 0;
            var letter = ele.value;
            for(i; i<tds.length;i++) {
            if(tds[i].innerHTML == letter){
                tds[i].style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
                //OR use this code; 
                //tds[i].classList.add("yellowColor");
            }
                else
                    tds[i].style.backgroundColor = "";
        }

        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```